# Суммирование значений DataFrame в python по условию

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть данные:

```
import pandas as pd 
df= pd.DataFrame({'Значение':[1,7,9,5,3,8,10,15,2]}) 
print (df)

     Значение
0         1
1         7
2         9
3         5
4         3
5         8
6        10
7        15
8         2
```

Нужно получить столбец значения которого будут равны сумме элементов текущего столбца выполняющих условие <= текущему значению ячейки.

Ответ должен получиться:

```
     Значение  Сумма
0         1      1
1         7      18
2         9      35
3         5      11
4         3      6
5         8      26
6        10      45
7        15      60
8         2      3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [15]: df
Out[15]:
   Val
0    1
1    7
2    9
3    5
4    3
5    8
6   10
7   15
8    2

In [16]: df["Sum"] = [df.loc[df["Val"] <= v, "Val"].sum() for v in df["Val"]]

In [17]: df
Out[17]:
   Val  Sum
0    1    1
1    7   18
2    9   35
3    5   11
4    3    6
5    8   26
6   10   45
7   15   60
8    2    3
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, нашел еще решение: df['Result'] = df.sort_values('Значение').cumsum()

Comment: @LesNick, ваше решение гораздо лучше!!!

Answer (score 1):

1. Создаем из столбца "Значения" список со значениями.
2. Применяем к столбцу "Значения" метод [`apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html). В теле функции суммируем элементы, которые подходят под условие.

```
In [57]: values = df['Значение'].values.tolist()

In [58]: df['Сумма'] = df['Значение'].apply(lambda x: sum(v for v in values if v <= x))

In [59]: df
Out[59]: 
   Значение  Сумма
0         1      1
1         7     18
2         9     35
3         5     11
4         3      6
5         8     26
6        10     45
7        15     60
8         2      3
```

Comment: Спасибо большое.